# jQuery DatePicker - Enable Specific Day - Code Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I cannot for the life of me work out why this code isn't working. I'm sure that I'm doing something really stupid, but I just cant find it! I'm currently just trying to disable all the dates bar "7-8-2013". Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>


<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Calender Control Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>

var enableDays = ["7-8-2013"];


 $(function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), var d = date.getDate(), var y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < enableDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray((d+1) + '-' + m + '-' + y,enableDays) != -1) {
            return [true];
            }
        }
        return [false];


    $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays});

  </script>
</head>
<body>



<div id="datepicker"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function(){

    var enableDays = ["7-8-2013"];

    function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
        var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'd-m-yy', date)
        if($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
            return [true];
        }
        return [false];
    }

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays});
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jMmzF/)

Comment: Ideal, thanks very much. I'll tick it when I can .. in 7 mins. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks. This answer made my day! Had to struggle with some minors issues when my controller returned a bunch of dates in another format but was easy once i could replicate the array.Cheers!

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined` this error message in my console when I try the above. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nice. Thank You @Arun

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$(document).ready(){

    var enableDays = ["7-8-2013"];
    function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
            var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'd-m-yy', date)
            if($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
                return [true];
            }
            return [false];
        }

        $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays});
    })
```

Hope it will help